# Figure (with caption and label) centered next to a list

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, captions, lists

I hope someone can help me place a figure (included a caption and label) next to a list. I want the list and the figure to be centered relative to each other. In the code I found as an answer to a similar question, I did not manage to add a caption and label to the figure.

The most important part is the caption and labelling of the figure. Hope someone can help me solve this problem! (I don't mind a completely new code if someone has a better one!)

This is the code I found in another answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\underline {Egenskaper for batterier}:
\par
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
        \item Item 3
        \item Item 4
        \item Item 5
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \strut\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\includegraphics[width=0.86\linewidth]{NMC performance.jpg}
\end{minipage}    

\end{document}
```

The pictures shows how it looks with the code and somewhat what I imagine it should look:

[image: How it looks in LaTeX]

[image: How I want it to look (made quick in Office Word)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the image in another `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{
  font={it,sf},
  labelsep=colon,
  justification=raggedright,
  singlelinecheck=false
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
Properties:
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3
  \item Item 4
  \item Item 5
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{NMC battery}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is it something like this you're after?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, threeparttable}
\DeclareCaptionFont{grey}{\color{lightgray}}

\begin{document}

\underline {Egenskaper for batterier}:

\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
        \item Item 3
        \item Item 4
        \item Item 5
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\captionsetup{font ={sf, it, small, grey} ,singlelinecheck = false, skip = 1ex}
 \centering\vspace*{3ex}
 \begin{measuredfigure}
 \includegraphics[width=0.86\linewidth]{NMCperformance}
 \caption{NMC battery}
 \end{measuredfigure}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This code did not work, I think there was something with the "treeparttable"

Comment: What's the error message(s)?